# Can I narrow the type of module imported using require in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Using the TypeScript 2.7.1 language service in VS Code, I can get hinting for a module imported into a JavaScript file as:

```
const aModule = require('./aModule')
```

However, the type inference from the module includes the generic `[x: string]: any;`

Which means that I can get autocomplete for valid exports from the module, but cannot get a warning if I use:

```
aModule.something_that_doesnt_exist()
```

Is there a way to specify that the object is not extendable?

Comment: Should have mentioned: I'm using non-transpiled JS that runs in Node, so ES6 modules don't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
import * as aModule from './aModule';
```

Comment: Should have mentioned: I'm using non-transpiled JS that runs in Node, so ES6 modules don't work....

Comment: This should get transpiled to amd/commonjs `require` internally if you have es5 target. Make sure you have `"module": "commonjs"` set in the config.